# Bulk upload to blob in Azure

Tags: .net, azure

I have about 10k images and I need to upload them to blob storage. Are there any tools that do bulk upload? I am also open to writing my own application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [ClumsyLeaf cloud explorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer). Let's you upload files to blob like an FTP client. Alterntaively [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/). Same idea.

Both allow you to select files from a directory and upload them in one go. Never tried with 10000 but it should work.

Comment: Sorry not a Mac user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553587/any-azure-storage-viewer-available-for-mac

Comment: Microsoft released a preview of their own Storage Explorer for Windows, Linux and OS X: https://github.com/Azure/deco

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage Studio is pretty good, too.

http://cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/

You can get a free 30 trial so no risk.  Especially if it's a one-shot deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows azure powershell to upload/download multiple files from azure storage.

For uploading multiple files, you can use the following command line.

```
ls -File -Recurse | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container upload
```

For downloading multiple blobs, you can use the following command line.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container containername -Blob blobname | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent
```

For more details, please refer to MSDN page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408487.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408562.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the existing tools are either payware or slow due to using few threads. TBH even the paid apps I've tried were quite slow, but the Azure API is really easy so I ended up writing my own command line tool, it's called azupload:

https://github.com/bviktor/azupload

It's free, released under the MIT license. It has both a C# and a Java version so you can deploy it easily both on Windows and Linux.

The C# version uses the internal .NET scheduler for starting new threads (it's usually 10-ish on my comp), while the Java version starts as many threads as you specify. It's quite performant, I've tested it with 700 images (20MiB total size) and 100 threads, it finished uploading them in 8 seconds.

Of course you gotta find a balance. If you start too many threads it will eventually slow down due to the overhead of the Java VM. Also, if you upload big files, it makes little sense to upload on 100 threads because in this case the bottleneck will be bandwidth, not the transactional overhead as with many small files. Furthermore, if you upload **many** files, the JVM will open files faster than it could close them so after a while you'll get `Too many open files` exceptions (for me that happened with 13k files @ 100 threads). So as a rule of thumb, the smaller the files the more the threads, but you should probably stop somewhere around 50.

Feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: omg. thank you. this has been such a huge PITA. adding a download option too and will hopefully send you a pull request soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own PowerShell/cmd script and use Az Cli Command in the script to upload files: az storage blob upload-batch

Steps:

1. Install Az CLI from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli
2. Get AccountKey & Name Credentials from Azure Blob Storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?tabs=azure-portal
3. Configure Az Cli Command to upload files based on your requirements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch

For example:

```
az storage blob upload-batch --account-key <AccountKey> --destination <DestinationFolder> --account-name <StorageAccountName> --destination-path <PathOfBlobToUpload> --source <SourcePath> --overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Option Explicit:

========Enums for choosing the format in which it is to be    pasted===== Enum eFormat

```
Picture = 1    Chart = 2    Table = 3
End Enum
```

=======================================================================

```
       Sub pGeneratePPT_Click()
       Dim lngWksCount         As Long    Dim lngLoopFirst        As Long    Dim lngLoopSecond       As Long    Dim lngSlide           
As Long    Dim objTemplate         As Object
       If MsgBox("Please click OK to generate the slide or click CANCEL to exit from the existing process.", vbOKCancel, "WARNING!")
=    vbCancel Then
       MsgBox "You have selected CANCEL please click the 'PPT converter' button again to convert into power point.",
vbInformation,    "Generation of slide presentation has been
cancelled."
       GoTo lblExit    End If
       lngWksCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count    Set objTemplate = Wks_INDEX.OLEObjects("objPPTTemplate")
       For lngLoopFirst = 1 To lngWksCount
       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(lngLoopFirst)
           For lngLoopSecond = 1 To .ChartObjects.Count
               If .ChartObjects(lngLoopSecond).Visible = True Then
                   lngSlide = lngSlide + 1
                   Call fPPTGenerator(objTemplate, .Name, lngSlide, Chart, .ChartObjects(lngLoopSecond).Name)
               End If
           Next lngLoopSecond
       End With    Next lngLoopFirst
       MsgBox "Done!", vbInformation
    lblExit:    lngWksCount = Empty    lngLoopFirst = Empty    lngLoopSecond = Empty    lngSlide = Empty    Set objTemplate =
Nothing
       End Sub


       Function fPPTGenerator(objOLEObject As Object, strSheetName As    String, lngSlide As Long, enumPasteAs As eFormat, _
                   strRangeOrChartName As String, Optional dblLeftInInches As Double, Optional dblTopInInches As Double, _
                   Optional dblHeightInInches As Double, Optional dblWidthInInches As Double)
       Dim lngLoopFirst            As Long    Dim lngLoopSecond           As Long    Dim objSlide                As Object 'PowerPoint.Slide  
Dim objTemplate             As Object 'Embbed File for template   
Dim objLayout               As Object    Dim objMainObject          
As Object    Dim varPicture              As Variant    Dim lngStatus
As Long    Dim objShape                As Object    Dim
strPathTemplate         As String    Dim objFileSystem           As
Object    Dim objFile                 As Object    Dim strFileName  
As String    Dim objPresTemp             As Object    Dim blnOpen   
As Boolean    Dim objPPT                  As Object    Dim objPres  
As Object    Dim blnNoError              As Boolean    Dim
blnTemplateNotFound     As Boolean
       lngStatus = Application.ScreenUpdating    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

           On Error GoTo lblNewPPT '****If the presentation is already open or not****    Set objPPT = GetObject(,
"Powerpoint.Application")    Set objPres = objPPT.presentations(1)  
blnOpen = True '**************************************************
       lblNewPPT: '****If the presentation is not opened already****    If blnOpen = False Then    On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1:
Err.Clear
       Set objPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
       Set objPres = objPPT.presentations.Add    End If '**************************************************    Set
objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    '**********Setting or adding the slides***********    If objPres.slides.Count <> lngSlide Then
       Set objLayout = objPres.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
       Set objSlide = objPres.slides.Addslide(lngSlide, objLayout)    Else
       Set objSlide = objPres.slides(lngSlide)    End If '**************************************************
       '*******Opening the embbed file in the editing mode*********    objOLEObject.Verb Verb:=xlEditBox    objPPT.WindowState = 2
'**************************************************
       '*****Open the presentation and saving it at the workbook path*****    Set objPresTemp = objPPT.activepresentation   
objPresTemp.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.pot"   
objPresTemp.Close
'**************************************************   
objPPT.WindowState = 2    For Each objFile In
objFileSystem.getfolder(ThisWorkbook.Path).Files
       If Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "pot" Then
           strFileName = objFile.Name
           blnTemplateNotFound = False
           Exit For
       Else
           blnTemplateNotFound = True
       End If    Next
       If blnTemplateNotFound = False Then
       objPres.ApplyTemplate FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.pot"     'Applying the Template to the new presentation  
Else
       MsgBox "Please embed the template in the" & vbNewLine & "'Microsoft Powerpoint 93-2003 Template' (*.pot) Format!",
vbCritical
       blnNoError = False
       GoTo lblExit:    End If
       Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFileName                              'Deleting the template thereafter applying
       For lngLoopFirst = 1 To objSlide.Shapes.Count                           'Removing the extra shapes on the new slide
       objSlide.Shapes(lngLoopFirst).Delete
       If objSlide.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
           lngLoopFirst = lngLoopFirst - 1
       Else
           Exit For
       End If    Next
       objPPT.Visible = True    Select Case enumPasteAs

       Case Picture:
           On Error GoTo lblErrorPic
           Set objMainObject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Shapes(strRangeOrChartName)

           objMainObject.CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture
           Set varPicture = objSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(2)
           varPicture.LockAspectRatio = False
           blnNoError = True lblErrorPic:
           If blnNoError = False Then
               MsgBox "Shape object not Found!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Worksheet: " & strSheetName & _
               vbNewLine & "Shape:         " & strRangeOrChartName, vbCritical
               On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1: Err.Clear
               GoTo lblExit
           End If

       Case Chart:
           On Error GoTo lblErrorChart
           Set objMainObject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Shapes(strRangeOrChartName)

           objMainObject.Copy
           objPPT.Activate
           objSlide.Select
           objPPT.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
           Set varPicture = objSlide.Shapes(1)
           blnNoError = True
            lblErrorChart:
           If blnNoError = False Then
               MsgBox "Chart not Found!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Worksheet: " & strSheetName & vbNewLine _
               & "Chart:          " & strRangeOrChartName, vbCritical
               On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1: Err.Clear
               GoTo lblExit
           End If

       Case Table:
           On Error GoTo lblError
           Set objMainObject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range(strRangeOrChartName)
           objMainObject.Copy
           objPPT.Activate
           objSlide.Select
           objPPT.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
           For Each objShape In objSlide.Shapes
               If Ucase(Left(objShape.Name, 5)) = "TABLE" Then
                   Set varPicture = objSlide.Shapes(objShape.Name)
                   Exit For
               End If
           Next
           blnNoError = True lblError:
           If blnNoError = False Then
               MsgBox "Range Not Found!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Range:          " & strRangeOrChartName & _
               vbNewLine & "Worksheet:  " & strSheetName, vbCritical
               On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1: Err.Clear
               GoTo lblExit
           End If    End Select
       With varPicture
       If dblLeftInInches <> 0 Then
           .Left = dblLeftInInches * 72
       Else
           .Left = 33
       End If

       If dblTopInInches <> 0 Then
           .Top = dblTopInInches * 72
       Else
           .Top = 118
       End If

       If dblHeightInInches <> 0 Then
           .Height = dblHeightInInches * 72
       Else
           .Height = 360
       End If

       If dblWidthInInches <> 0 Then
           .Width = dblWidthInInches * 72
       Else
           .Width = 655
       End If    End With
       objPPT.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom = 100
    '    objPres.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PPT_" & Format(Now(), "dd_mmm_yyyy") & ".pptx"
    lblExit:    objPPT.WindowState = 2
       lngLoopFirst = Empty    lngLoopSecond = Empty    Set objSlide = Nothing    Set objTemplate = Nothing    Set objLayout = Nothing    Set objMainObject = Nothing    Set varPicture = Nothing    Set
objShape = Nothing    strPathTemplate = Empty    Set objFileSystem =
Nothing    Set objFile = Nothing    strFileName = Empty    Set
objPresTemp = Nothing    blnOpen = Empty    Set objPres = Nothing
       Application.ScreenUpdating = lngStatus    lngStatus = Empty
       If blnNoError = False Then
       objPPT.Quit
       End    End If

    End Function
       ======================================
       Option Explicit Option Compare Text
       Private adoConn              As Object Private adoRset                 As Object
       Private Const mc_strModuleName      As String =    "modExportExcelDataToAccess" Private Const strMsgBoxTitle        As 
String = "Uploader" Private Const strDbName             As String = 
"Test.mdb"
       Sub test()
       Call ExportDataIntoAccess( _
                               db_FullPath:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & strDbName, _
                               db_tblName:="Test" & CLng(Timer), _
                               xl_FileFullPath:=ThisWorkbook.FullName, _
                               xl_SheetName:="Sheet1", _
                               xl_DataRange:="$A$1:$E$200000", _
                               xl_HeaderYes:=True, _
                               blnDelTableExistingData:=True)
    End Sub
       Sub ExportDataIntoAccess( _
                           ByVal db_FullPath As String, _
                           ByVal db_tblName As String, _
                           ByVal xl_FileFullPath As String, _
                           ByVal xl_SheetName As String, _
                           ByVal xl_DataRange As String, _
                           ByVal xl_HeaderYes As Boolean, _
                           Optional blnDelTableExistingData As Boolean = False)


       Dim wbkWorkBook         As Workbook    Dim wksWorkSheet        As Worksheet    Dim varData             As Variant    Dim lngLoopD  
As Long    Dim lngLoopA            As Long    Dim lngLoop           
As Long    Dim lngFldsCount        As Long    Dim lngLastCol        
As Long    Dim lngLastRow          As Long    Dim strSQL            
As String    Dim strTemp             As String    Dim lngCounter    
As Long    Dim dblSum              As Double    Dim dbFlds()        
As String    Dim dataFlds            As Variant    Dim varFound     
As Variant    Dim rngFirstCell        As Range    Dim rngData       
As Range    Dim strAddress          As String    Dim lngScreenUp    
As Long    Dim lngCalc             As Long    Dim dtTime            
As Date
          dtTime = Time
           Const DataTypeNumeric   As String = "Single"    Const DataTypeString    As String = "varchar(255)"    Const
DataTypeDateTime  As String = "DateTime"

       'Setting Table Name    If Left(db_tblName, 1) <> "[" Then
       db_tblName = "[" & db_tblName    End If    If Right(db_tblName, 1) <> "]" Then
       db_tblName = db_tblName & "]"    End If
           'Checking file path is correct.    If Not IsFileExists(xl_FileFullPath) Then Exit Sub
       'Disabling Application Level Events    With Application
       .EnableEvents = 0
       lngCalc = .Calculation
       lngScreenUp = .ScreenUpdating
       '.ScreenUpdating = 0
       .DisplayAlerts = 0
       .Calculation = xlCalculationManual    End With
       'Checking if given file and sheet is available or not    On Error Resume Next    If Not IsFileOpen(xl_FileFullPath) Then
       Set wbkWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(xl_FileFullPath)    ElseIf LCase(ThisWorkbook.FullName) = LCase(xl_FileFullPath) Then
       Set wbkWorkBook = ThisWorkbook    Else
       If IsFileOpen(xl_FileFullPath) Then
           MsgBox "File is already open. Please save file and close it first to upload data.", vbCritical, strMsgBoxTitle
           GoTo QuickExit
       Else
           Set wbkWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(xl_FileFullPath)
       End If    End If    Set wksWorkSheet = wbkWorkBook.Worksheets(CStr(xl_SheetName))
       'Error handling    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Worksheet '" & xl_SheetName & " doesn't exists", vbInformation
       Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
       GoTo QuickExit    End If
       Call OpenDB(db_FullPath)    With wksWorkSheet

       'Data Range
       Set rngData = .Range(xl_DataRange)

       'checking for header if available
       If xl_HeaderYes Then
           dataFlds = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rngData.Resize(1)))
       Else
           adoRset.Open "Select * From " & db_tblName & " Where 1=2", adoConn, 3, 3

           ReDim datafld(1 To adoRset.Fields.Count)
           For lngLoop = 0 To adoRset.Fields.Count - 1
               Select Case adoRset.Fields(lngLoop).Type
                   Case 202 'adVarWChar
                       datafld(lngLoop + 1) = 202 'advarWChar
                   Case 4 'adSingle
                       datafld(lngLoop + 1) = 4 'adSingle
                   Case 5 'adDouble
                       datafld(lngLoop + 1) = 5 'adDouble
                   Case 7 'adDate
                       datafld(lngLoop + 1) = 7 'adDate
               End Select
           Next lngLoop
       End If
       varData = rngData    End With    If LCase(wbkWorkBook.FullName) <> LCase(xl_FileFullPath) Then
wbkWorkBook.Close (0)
       On Error GoTo 0    'Checking if table is already exist  or not.    If Not blnTableExistsInDB(CStr(db_tblName)) Then
       'Creating table
       If xl_HeaderYes Then
           If IsArray(varData) And IsArray(dataFlds) Then
               strTemp = "Create Table " & CStr(db_tblName) & vbLf & "("
               ReDim datafld(1 To UBound(dataFlds, 1))
               For lngLoopD = 1 To UBound(dataFlds, 1)
                   If IsNumeric(varData(2, lngLoopD)) And Len(varData(2, lngLoopD)) Then
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopD = 1, "[" & dataFlds(lngLoopD) & "]", ",[" & dataFlds(lngLoopD) & "]") & "
" & DataTypeNumeric
                       datafld(lngLoopD) = 5 'adDouble
                   ElseIf IsDate(varData(2, lngLoopD)) Then
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopD = 1, "[" & dataFlds(lngLoopD) & "]", ",[" & dataFlds(lngLoopD) & "]") & "
" & DataTypeDateTime
                       datafld(lngLoopD) = 7 'adDate
                   Else
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopD = 1, "[" & dataFlds(lngLoopD) & "]", ",[" & dataFlds(lngLoopD) & "]") & "
" & DataTypeString
                       datafld(lngLoopD) = 202 'advarWChar
                   End If
               Next lngLoopD
               strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & ")"
               adoConn.Execute Replace(strTemp, "''", "Null")
           End If
       Else
           If IsArray(varData) Then
               strTemp = "Create Table " & CStr(db_tblName) & vbLf & "("
               For lngLoopD = 1 To UBound(varData, 2)
                   If IsNumeric(varData(2, lngLoopD)) And Len(varData(2, lngLoopD)) Then
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopD = 1, "[Field" & lngLoopD & "]", ",[Field" & lngLoopD & "]") & " " &   
DataTypeNumeric
                   ElseIf IsDate(varData(2, lngLoopD)) Then
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopD = 1, "[Field" & lngLoopD & "]", ",[Field" & lngLoopD & "]") & " " &   
DataTypeNumeric
                   Else
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopD = 1, "[Field" & lngLoopD & "]", ",[Field" & lngLoopD & "]") & " " &   
DataTypeString
                   End If
               Next lngLoopD
               strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & ")"
               adoConn.Execute Replace(strTemp, "''", "Null")
           End If
       End If    Else
       'Delete existing data from the table.
       If blnDelTableExistingData Then
           strSQL = "Delete * FROM " & CStr(db_tblName)
           adoConn.Execute strSQL
       End If    End If
       'Inserting data into the table row by row.    On Error GoTo EarlyExit    If IsArray(varData) Then
       For lngLoopD = LBound(varData) + 1 To UBound(varData, 1)
           strTemp = "INSERT INTO " & CStr(db_tblName) & " VALUES ("
           For lngLoopA = 1 To UBound(datafld)

               If datafld(lngLoopA) = 5 Or datafld(lngLoopA) = 4 Then 'adDouble 'adSigle
                   If Not IsEmpty(varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA)) Then
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopA = 1, varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA), "," & varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA))
                   ElseIf IsEmpty(varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA)) Then
                       strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopA = 1, "NULL", ",NULL")
                   End If
               ElseIf datafld(lngLoopA) = 7 Then 'adDate
                   varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA) = Replace(varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA), "#", "")
                   varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA) = Evaluate("=VALUE(""" & varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA) & """)")
                   strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopA = 1, varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA), "," & varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA))
               ElseIf datafld(lngLoopA) = 202 Then 'advarWChar
                   varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA) = Replace(varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA), "'", "''")
                   varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA) = Replace(varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA), """", """""")
                   strTemp = strTemp & vbLf & IIf(lngLoopA = 1, "'" & varData(lngLoopD, lngLoopA) & "'", ",'" & varData(lngLoopD,   
lngLoopA) & "'")
               End If

               'Debug.Print strTemp
           Next lngLoopA
           strTemp = strTemp & ")"
           'Debug.Print "ROW: " & lngLoopD '  & ":" & strTemp
           Call StatusBar(lngLoopD & " Out Of " & UBound(varData) - 1 & " Records inserted into " & db_tblName & " ...")
           adoConn.Execute Replace(strTemp, "''", "Null")
       Next lngLoopD
       Call StatusBar(lngLoopD & "Records are inserted successfully." & vbLf & "Process Started at " & dtTime & " and   
Finished at " & Time)
       MsgBox lngLoopD & "Records are inserted successfully." & vbLf & "Process Started at " & dtTime & " and Finished at " & Time,   
vbInformation, strMsgBoxTitle
       Call StatusBar(, False)    End If
    EarlyExit:    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Error #:" & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
       Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
       Stop    Else
       Call StatusBar("", False)    End If    Erase varData    dblSum = Empty    dataFlds = Empty QuickExit:    With Application
       .EnableEvents = 1
       .ScreenUpdating = lngScreenUp
       .DisplayAlerts = 1
       .Calculation = lngCalc    End With
       Call CloseDB
       End Sub
       Private Function IsFileExists(ByVal FullFileName As String) As    Boolean    IsFileExists = False    On Error Resume Next   
IsFileExists = CBool(Len(Dir(FullFileName))) End Function
       Private Sub OpenDB(ByVal strDBPath As String)
       Set adoConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")    Set adoRset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")    adoConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & CStr(strDBPath) &
";"
    End Sub Private Sub CloseDB()
       On Error Resume Next    If adoRset.State <> 0 Then adoRset.Close    If adoConn.State <> 0 Then adoConn.Close    On
Error GoTo 0: Err.Clear
    End Sub

       Private Function blnTableExistsInDB(strTableName As String) As    Boolean
       Dim rst         As Object    Dim strTbl      As String
       strTbl = strTableName
       Set rst = adoConn.OpenSchema(20) 'adSchemaTables
       If Left(strTbl, 1) = "[" And Right(strTbl, 1) = "]" Then
       strTbl = Mid(strTbl, 2, Len(strTbl) - 2)    End If
       rst.Filter = "TABLE_TYPE='TABLE' and TABLE_NAME='" & strTbl & "'"    On Error Resume Next    blnTableExistsInDB =
(Ucase(rst.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value) = Ucase(strTbl))    On Error
GoTo 0    If Err.Number <> 0 Then blnTableExistsInDB = False    Set
rst = Nothing
    End Function
       Private Function IsFileOpen(ByVal FileName As String)
       Dim iFilenum As Long    Dim iErr As Long
        On Error Resume Next    iFilenum = FreeFile()    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum    Close iFilenum    iErr
= Err    On Error GoTo 0
        Select Case iErr    Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False    Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True    Case Else: Error iErr    End Select
     End Function
       Private Sub StatusBar(Optional strMsg As String = vbNullString,    Optional blnShow As Boolean = True)
       DoEvents    If Not blnShow Then Application.StatusBar = blnShow: Exit Sub    Application.StatusBar = strMsg
    End Sub
```

Comment: Pls format the answer. Its impossible to follow what has been answered in the current format.