# Any Azure Storage viewer available for Mac?

Tags: macos, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I want to be able to view my Azure Table storage account, tables, data, etc, from my MacBook.  I haven't seen any applications or even sites that would allow me to do this.  Is there any way I can do this without using a Virtual Machine?

Comment: I know this question got closed, but for anyone looking, this might be your solution: [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/)

Answer (score 13):

The correct answer is use Microsoft's new tool: http://storageexplorer.com/

Comment: Cyberduck can access blob storage, but sadly not tables or queues

Comment: Also worth noting that CyberDuck is $24 usd currently so it is not a free option.

Comment: @PWKad i think that is only from the app store, I downloaded it from the website and currently use it without paying for it

Comment: @AntiVeeranna Where can I get guidelines how to blob storage on cyberduck?

Comment: Microsoft is working on a cross-os application which allows you to: github.com/Azure/deco . Currently it does not support tables and queues but it should be in the future. Otherwise you can go to portal.azure.com , in which you can view the stuff the questioneer asked about ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [zud.io](http://zud.io/) - it is a browser-based Windows Azure Storage explorer.

> **UPDATE:**
> **zud.io link is not working, source is down.**

Comment: not working anymore

Comment: Leads to spam, don't go there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Neil's answer: While this isn't a complete solution, you can browse storage containers and blobs via the Azure portal itself - look at the Containers tab under your storage account within the portal. You can also browse blob storage via the [CLI](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/) if you're into command-line stuff.